# java and android exception output

Tags: java, android, debugging, exception

when i run the android app, i got a exception , at the below , there is a string **" E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   ... 8 more"** , it seems that there other message didn't 
print , anyone know how to print the message of the 8 more?

thanks!

> E/AndroidRuntime( 2361): FATAL EXCEPTION: http2
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361): java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.cert.CertificateException: org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Exception: ASN.1 UTCTime: wrong format for DER, identifier at [139]
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:674)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:474)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at android.net.http.CertificateChainValidator.doHandshakeAndValidateServerCertificates(CertificateChainValidator.java:86)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at android.net.http.HttpsConnection.openConnection(HttpsConnection.java:309)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at android.net.http.Connection.openHttpConnection(Connection.java:407)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at android.net.http.Connection.processRequests(Connection.java:260)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at android.net.http.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:142)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361): Caused by: javax.security.cert.CertificateException: org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Exception: ASN.1 UTCTime: wrong format for DER, identifier at [139]
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(X509Certificate.java:104)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(X509Certificate.java:223)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:658)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2361):   ... 8 more

Answer (score 0):

You can view the full stack trace by pulling /data/anr/traces.txt as follows -

```
adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt
```

Then just open traces.txt in an editor and enjoy!!

Comment: thanks, but i have not found the anr directory in data dierctory.